# flask image not showing 404 even if the image is in static folder

Tags: python, html, flask

Even after adding image to static foldee, the image doesnt show in index file. Also error says file cannot be found.
What could be the cause of this?

```
https://i.stack.imgur.com/uhTJV.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/bjOuZ.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/rakbK.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/uqKWR.png
```

I tried moving image in diferrent folder as you can see in the image i have two location inside static and static/images folder but still the same error.
I cannot also browse the image directly via url

Comment: Can you show the html code where you bind in the image?

Comment: You have your `static` folder inside `templates`.  That's wrong.  Move it to the same level as `templates`.